# Opening of existing data with Primefaces Editor

Tags: editor, primefaces

I have some sample data. I want to open the `data(Text)` with `Primefaces Editor`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to "connect" it to your bean

```
<p:editor id="editor" value="#{myBean.myValue}" width="600"/>
```

look at the showcase

[PrimeFaces - ShowCase  - Editor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf)